# Why isn't there a Light.color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game for an assignment using Unity. I want to have a light change color when a specific object gets next to it.

I am getting an error saying

> "Error CS1061  'Light' does not contain a definition for 'color' and no extension method 'color' accepting a first argument of type 'Light' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Every website I read said there is a `Light.color`, including the Unity documentation. Every one of them has different issues regarding `Light.color`.

**Code:**

```
Light lc = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();
lc.color = Color.green;
```

All I want to change the color of light without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

By default, new scripts created via the Unity Editor will have "using UnityEngine" near the beginning.

The 'Light' you are referring too is a native Unity object, and thus you either need to include "using UnityEngine" or reference the object as UnityEngine.Light

It is not a fault of theirs to not mention this in the documentation, as everything in the documentation is assumed to be part of the UnityEngine API.

Answer (score 0):

Nvmd, fixed it

if anyone else gets this problem, it is probably because Unity forgot to mention in its documentation that is it:
UnityEngine.Light
not:
Light

Comment: Perhaps they expect you to have `using UnityEngine;`

Comment: If you need to write `UnityEngine.Light` while you have `using UnityEngine` at the top of your script, it means you have created your own `Light` class "hiding" Unity's. So, please, don't blame Unity.